# Deselect UICollectionView cell on second tap

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have both tableViews and collectionViews in my project app. In both tables and collections, I want a row/cell to be selected when first tapped, and deselected when tapped second time.

With the tableView, I found a fairly straightforward and simple solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693402/uitableview-tap-to-deselect-cell), which works great.

CollectionView, on the other hand, turned out to be a whole different type of beast. Unlike tableView, there is no `willSelectItemAt` delegate method, so there is no way to check if item was in selected state before the second tap is registered. Implementing `shouldDeselectItemAt` and `didDeselectItemAt` gives no result - these methods never get called on a cell that's already selected when tapped.

The only plausible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37222260/toggle-select-deselect-state-of-a-uicollectionview-cell-on-tap-swift) suggests creating a `UIButton` for each collectionView cell, but should it really be that complicated?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try using the "shouldSelectItem" UIColllectionViewDelegate method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let item = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    if item?.isSelected ?? false {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    } else {
        collectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great solution! For the `else` statement I used `return true` instead of `selectItem()`, because I need some logic to be done in `didSelectItemAt()` method, and now it does the job just as expected)

Answer (score 10):

A shorter version of [@pkorosec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8270044/pkorosec) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795425/5840990), with exact the same effect, is the following:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)?.isSelected ?? false {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

An alternative, suggested by [@Manav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141220/manav), is:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    if collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(indexPath) ?? false {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Here is a alternative condition, if one doesn't want to ask the collection view for the cell: `collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(indexPath) == true`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option, that I personally think is way cleaner, is to allow multiple selection on collection view and then manually deselect the currently selected item before next selection.

First step: allow multiple selection

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}
```

Second step: manually deselect previously selected item

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.forEach { ip in
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: ip, animated: true)
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want multiple selection, try this code for unSelection.

```
var selectedIndex:Int?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CategoryCollectionViewCell
    if selectedIndex == indexPath.row {
        selectedIndex = nil
        // unselect code here
    } else {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        // Select code here
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // unselect code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting a similar solution but calling the delegate, so you **keep everything in sync**, simulating an actual deselection (plus a slightly clear naming):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    let isSelectedAlready = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.contains(indexPath)
    if isSelectedAlready == true {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        collectionView.delegate?.collectionView?(collectionView, didDeselectItemAt: indexPath)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```